# !pip install syft==0.8.0.post2 hook = sy.TorchHook(torch) but showing AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'TorchHook'

Tags: python, pytorch, pysyft

I am using google colab to execute the program. Pythoon veersion is 3.10.11
!pip install syft==0.8.0.post2 hook = sy.TorchHook(torch) but showing AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'TorchHook'

!pip install syft==0.8.0.post2
hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)
but showing AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'TorchHook'
Please fix the problem regarding syft==0.8.0.post2

Comment: [`TorchHook` does not appear in the documentation for PySyft](https://openmined.github.io/PySyft/search.html?q=TorchHook). Why do you think this should exist?

Answer (score 1):

sy.TorchHook() has been deprecated since the release of PySyft 0.3.0. It is not needed anymore to create VirtualWorkers or execute any other functions.

In general you can directly write :

```
import syft as sy
client = sy.virtualWorker(id="client")
```

Comment: I am using syft==0.3.0. But I am getting error: AttributeError: module 'syft' has no attribute 'VirtualMachine'

Comment: @ChristopherMarlowe Use `VirtualWorker` instead of `VirtualMachine`. Hope this helps !

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\syft.py", line 1, in <module>
    import syft as sy
  File "E:\PhD\Summer 2023\udacity-FL\syft.py", line 2, in <module>
    client = sy.virtualWorker(id="client")
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'syft' has no attribute 'virtualWorker' (most likely due to a circular import)

Answer (score 0):

So far, I checked and I found that there are no **VirtualWorker** nor **VirtualMachine** attributes but **Worker**. Which we have to give it a **name** not **id**. For example, **bob=sy.Worker(name='bob')**. Furthermore, to check the value stored **print(bob._objects)** is no longer working but **print(bob.client_cache)**. At the same time, after establishing a new tensor variable, there are no attributes such as **send()** and **get()**, which means there must be another way to send and receive tensor values over Pysyft based clients.